# Square element in a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Which elements of a cyclic group are squares (an element $g$ of a group $G$ is a square if $g=h^2$ for some $h \in G$)?

Here is my solution; is it correct?

Let $G = \{ 1,a,a^2, \ldots , a^n \}$

If $n$ is even, then
$1,a^2, a^4 \ldots , a^n$ are squares

If $n$ is odd, then
$1,a^2, a^4 \ldots , a^{n-1}$ are squares

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  What do you need help with?

Comment: Is my solution correct?

Comment: No, it is not.  Try looking at some concrete examples to see why.

Comment: To add to @Qudit's suggestion, look at the residue classes modulo some small number, such as $\Bbb Z_3$. If you not familiar with this, think of clock arithmetic, where your clock has only the numbers $0$, $1,$, and $2$. Remember that the operation here is adding, not multiplying.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, then the number of squares is $n$ if $n$ is odd (every element can be written as a square). If $n$ is even, then the number of squares if $\frac{n}{2}$.